# C++ dereferencing for std::priority_queue::top

Tags: c++, reference, priority-queue

Documentation states `std::priority_queue::top` returns a constant reference to the top element in the priority_queue, but when printing the top element, the unary dereference operator is not used.

```
// priority_queue::top
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <queue>          // std::priority_queue

int main ()
{
  std::priority_queue<int> mypq;

  mypq.push(10);
  mypq.push(20);
  mypq.push(15);

  std::cout << "mypq.top() is now " << mypq.top() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Is `top()` being implicitly dereferenced or is the returned value a copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is top() being implicitly dereferenced or is the returned value a copy?

No there's no value copy, unless you make one. As from the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top) `std::priority_queue::top()` returns a `const &T`:

> > `const_reference top() const;`
> >     Returns reference to the top element in the priority queue. This element will be removed on a call to pop(). If default comparison function is used, the returned element is also the greatest among the elements in the queue.

If you use

```
 int x = mypq.top();
```

a copy is made. If you use

```
 const int& x = mypq.top();
```

you'll have a direct (const) reference.

> but when printing the top element, the unary dereference operator is not used.

Supposed you meant one of the [dereferncing operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access), dereferencing references isn't needed at all, think of aliases to the original value instead. You can overload these operators though for `T`, but that  doesn't affect `std::priority_queue::top()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to dereference a reference. You only need to dereference a pointer, not a reference.